# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key '......'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Controller**

```
DepartmentLevel departmentlevel = new DepartmentLevel();
ViewBag.DepartmentLevel = 
    new SelectList(db.DepartmentLevels, "DepartmentLevelId", "DepartmentLevelDesc",
    departmentlevel.DepartmentLevelId).OrderBy(a => a.Text);
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentLevel", ViewData["DepartmentLevel"] as SelectList,
                   "All Department", new { @style = "width:200px;" })
```

What is the problem?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `ViewBag` instead of `ViewData` in your `Controller`. So you should use `ViewBag` in your `View` too, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DepartmentLevel", ViewBag.DepartmentLevel as SelectList,
                   "All Department", new { @style = "width:200px;" })
```